# How do I copy a percentage of my files into new directories correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, copy, shutil

I am working on a function where I am supposed to copy a percentage of files from a SOURCE directory into two different directories, a training one and a testing one. The function looks like this

`def copy_file(source, training, testing, split_size):`

where:

-source is the source directory I want to copy from

-training is a directory to copy to

-testing is another directory to copy to

-split_size is the percentage of source i want to copy into testing and training, expressed as a decimal point (e.g. if split_size is 0.9 i will copy 90% of source to training and 10% to testing)

My code currently looks like this

```
def split_data(SOURCE, TRAINING, TESTING, SPLIT_SIZE):
    #get the source image names in a list
    source_images = os.listdir(SOURCE)
    splitVal_training = int(round(SPLIT_SIZE*len(source_images))) #get 1350 aka 90% of all the documents
    splitVal_testing = int(round((1 - SPLIT_SIZE)*len(source_images))) #get the remainder of the split_size, aka 10% of all images
    
    
    
    training_list = random.sample(source_images, splitVal_training) #create a new list with 1350 elements of the original list
    print(len(training_list))
    testing_list = [image for image in source_images if not image in training_list]
    print(len(testing_list))
    
    
    
    for image in training_list:
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE,image),os.path.join(TRAINING,image))
        
    for image in testing_list:
            copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE,image),os.path.join(TESTING,image))


CAT_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Cat/"
TRAINING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/"
TESTING_CATS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/"
DOG_SOURCE_DIR = "/tmp/PetImages/Dog/"
TRAINING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/"
TESTING_DOGS_DIR = "/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/"

split_size = .9
split_data(CAT_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_CATS_DIR, TESTING_CATS_DIR, split_size)
split_data(DOG_SOURCE_DIR, TRAINING_DOGS_DIR, TESTING_DOGS_DIR, split_size)
```

When I run it and get the length of my training and testing lists I get the correct results, 1350 and 150, respectively. However when I check the length of my directories in the next cell of code (I am working on Google Colab), I keep getting 1500 for both training directories, and a random number for each testing directories. Why is this? Shoulnd't I be getting the same numbers as those I get when I print the length of the training and testing lists?

```
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/cats/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/training/dogs/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/cats/')))
print(len(os.listdir('/tmp/cats-v-dogs/testing/dogs/')))

# Expected output:
# 1350
# 1350
# 150
# 150

#Actual output:
#1500
#1500
#1309
#1203
```

UPDATE: After I cleared the kernel and ran this again today I got the right output on the first run. The second and subsequent runs gave me random numbers again. Could any files that I ran on the first try be staying in the folders and adding up to the intended output?

Another issue that I haven't been able to resolve is that I am supposed to check whether each file has a size greater than 0. to do that I tried editing my for loops to look like this

```
for image in training_list: 
     if os.path.gets_size(image) > 0 :
         copyfile(os.path.join(SOURCE,image),os.path.join(TRAINING,image))
```

However every time I run it I get an error saying that the file doesn't exist, is this the wrong way to check for the size of a file?

Comment: Were the output directories empty before you ran the code?

Comment: Yeah, they're newly created so they should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Because you aren't persisting the filenames that are randomly selected for training vs testing between runs, you will eventually end up with 1500 files in training and 1500 files in testing.

Testing will take much longer to get there since you're using .9 as your split_size. The apparently random size of your testing data `1203` is the result of ~8 runs of your program with some slop from the `int(round(SPLIT_SIZE)` you're using.

You can solve this by persisting your initial split into training/test either in a serialized structure or by checking the contents of both /training_location/ and /test_location/ before adding anything to either.

Generally speaking, I would avoid using the `os` package for things like this in favor of `pathlib`. Pathlib will get you the lists of files and also the size

Comment: thanks! is there a preferred method for persisting them? I have never even heard the term before. As for using os, it's for an assignment so I was asked to use os as the library to work with.

Comment: Given this is an assignment, my help here will be precise and complete. 'Persist' just means that you need to find a way to save your split if you intend to make repeated calls to `copy_file()` -- if you don't find a way to save and re-load your original split then you will find that eventually you'll end up with 1500 files in both directories (though it make take quite a few runs).